# Component data doesn't update the new value after the status change by getting the new result from POST function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

The Vue.js 2 code below is the data form that I sent it to the backend. I used vuex to deal with my data status. After I use POST function, the result which returns from the backend changes the data value of sampleId. The value is created by the database and will automatically plus one every time there is a new piece of data. I've used console log to check my status after use POST function and the status successfully changed (which means it not only successfully created by the backend but also sent it back to frontend successfully.). However, I still can't see the updated result of sampleId in the frontend after I press button. Can any one please help me to revise my code?

```
<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                    <h2 class="newSample">2. Add New Sample Data</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="productName">Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" v-model="sample.productName" name="productName" v-validate="'required'" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('productName') }" />
                        <div v-if="submitted && errors.has('productName')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('productName') }}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="OracleItemNum">Oracle Item Number</label>
                        <input type="number" v-model="sample.OracleItemNum" name="OracleItemNum" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('OracleItemNum') }" />
                        <div v-if="submitted && errors.has('OracleItemNum')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('OracleItemNum') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="batchSize">Batch Size</label>
                        <input type="number" v-model="sample.batchSize" name="batchSize" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('batchSize') }" />
                        <div v-if="submitted && errors.has('batchSize')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('batchSize') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numCntrRecv">Number of Containers Received</label>
                        <input type="number" v-model="sample.numCntrRecv" name="numCntrRecv" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('numCntrRecv') }" />
                        <div v-if="submitted && errors.has('numCntrRecv')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('numCntrRecv') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="aqlLevel">AQL Level</label>
                        <select name="aqlLevel" v-model="sample.aqlLevel">
                            <option value="I" v-if="samples.all.qualified == 'I' || !checkOracleItemNum.length || samples.all.qualified == 'S-3'">I</option>
                            <option value="II" v-if="samples.all.qualified == false || !checkOracleItemNum.length" >II</option>
                            <option value="III" v-if="samples.all.qualified == 'I' || !checkOracleItemNum.length">III (Tighted Level)</option>
                            <option value="S-3" v-if="samples.all.qualified == 'S-3' || !checkOracleItemNum.length || samples.all.qualified == 'I'" >S-3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" v-if="sample.aqlLevel == 'I'">
                        <label for="fullOrReduced">FULL or REDUCED</label>
                        <select name="fullOrReduced" v-model="sample.fullOrReduced" v-if="sample.fullOrReduced !== null">
                            <option value="FULL" v-if="sample.aqlLevel == 'I'">FULL</option>
                            <option value="REDUCED" v-if="sample.aqlLevel == 'I'">REDUCED</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="!sample.productName.length || !sample.OracleItemNum.length || !sample.batchSize.length || !sample.numCntrRecv.length || !sample.aqlLevel.length">Add</button>
                        <img v-show="sample.adding" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- TODO not showing sampleId instantly -->
                <div class="qualified" v-if="(samples.all.sample !== undefined || samples.all.sample !== null) && submitted === true && samples.all.sample.sampleId !== undefined" >The Sample ID is {{samples.all.sample.sampleId}} </div>
```

The Javascript part for the form page:

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            sample:{
                productName: '',
                OracleItemNum: 0,
                batchSize: 0,
                numCntrRecv: 0,
                aqlLevel: '',
                fullOrReduced: '',
                sampleSize: 0,
                referenceNum: 0,
                sampleId: 0
            },
            checkOracleItemNum: 0,
            showIorS3: false,
            submitted: false,
            showResult: false,
            canNotEmpty: false,
            sampleId: 0
        }
    },
    created () {
        //this.getSampleId();
    },
    computed: {
        
        // workable
        // ...mapState({
        //     account: state => state.account, 
        //     users: state => state.users.all}, ['sample'])
        ...mapState({
            account: state => state.account, 
            users: state => state.users.all,
            samples: state => state.samples
        }),
        count() {
            console.log(this.$store.samples);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('samples', {
            addNewSample: 'addNewSample',
            testQualified: 'testQualified'
        }),
        ...mapActions('users', {
            getAllUsers: 'getAll',
            deleteUser: 'delete'
        }),
        handleSubmit (e) {
            this.submitted = true;
            this.addNewSample(this.sample);
        },
        handleTest (e){
            //this.qualified = true;
            // if(this.checkOracleItemNum == ''){
            //     sample.qualifying = false
            // }
            this.testQualified(this.checkOracleItemNum);
            //console.log(e.target.elements.);
            //console.log(this.testQualified(this.checkOracleItemNum));            
        },
        getResult(){
            this.showResult = true;
        },
        reload(){
            this.$forceUpdate();
        }
    },
    watch: {
        sampleId(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(`Updating from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`);

        // Do whatever makes sense now
        // if (newValue === 'success') {
        //     this.complex = {
        //     deep: 'some deep object',
        //     };
        // }
    }}
};
</script>
```

This is what I did in the action part in the store:

```
addNewSample({dispatch, commit}, sample){
        commit('addNewSampleRequest', sample);
        sampleService.addNewSample(sample).then(
            sample => {
                console.log(sample.sampleId);
                if(sample != null && sample.sampleId != undefined || sample.sampleId != null) commit('addNewSampleSuccess', sample);
            },
            error => {
                commit('addNewSampleFailure', error);
                dispatch('alert/error', error, { root: true });
            }
        )
    },
```

This is the mutation part of the code:

```
    addNewSampleRequest(state, sample) {
        state.sample = sample;
    },
    addNewSampleSuccess(state, sample) {
        state.sample = sample;
        console.log(state);
    },
    addNewSampleFailure(state, error) {
        state.sample = null;
    }
```

I add index.js file to below to reply @Phil 's question. (The code above this file is written in samples.module.js file)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import { alert } from './alert.module';
import { account } from './account.module';
import { users } from './users.module';
import { samples } from './samples.module';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        alert,
        account,
        users,
        samples
    }
});
```

This is what I get in my console after I press the button. 130 is the sampleId which is printed because the console.log in addNewSample() function, and the object below is the new status that return from the backend.
[image]

My sample.module.js file looks like this below:

```
import { sampleService } from '../_services';
const state = {
    all: {}
};
const actions = {
    getSampleResult({commit}, id){
        sampleService.getSampleResult(id).then(
            sample => commit('getSampleResultSuccess', id),
            error => commit('getSampleResultFailure', {id, error: error.toString()})
        );
    },
    getAllSamples({commit}){
        commit('getAllSampleRequest');
        sampleService.getAllSamples().then(
            sample => commit('getAllSampleSuccess', sample),
            error => commit('getAllSampleFailure', error)
        );
    },
    addNewSample({dispatch, commit}, sample){
        commit('addNewSampleRequest', sample);
        sampleService.addNewSample(sample).then(
            sample => {
                console.log(sample);
                if(sample != null && sample.sampleId != undefined || sample.sampleId != null) commit('addNewSampleSuccess', sample);
            },
            error => {
                commit('addNewSampleFailure', error);
                dispatch('alert/error', error, { root: true });
            }
        )
    },
    testQualified({commit}, OracleItemNum){
        sampleService.testIfNewOrQualified(OracleItemNum).then(           
            isQualified => {
                console.log(isQualified)
                commit('testQualifiedSuccess', isQualified)
            }           
        )
    }
}

const mutations = {
    getAllSampleRequest(state) {
        state.all = { loadingSamples: true };
    },
    getAllSampleSuccess(state, samples) {
        console.log(state);
        state.all = { samples: samples };
    },
    getAllSampleFailure(state, error) {
        state.all = { error };
    },
    // getSampleResultRequest(state, id) {
    //     console.log(state.all.samples);
    //     console.log(id);
    //     // state.all.samples = state.all.samples.map(sample =>
    //     //     sample.sampleId === id
    //     //         ? { ...sample, getSampleResult: true }
    //     //         : sample
    //     // )
    //     // console.log(state);
    // },
    getSampleResultSuccess(state, id) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(state);
        state.all.samples = state.all.samples.filter(sample => sample.sampleId == id)
        console.log(state);
    },
    getSampleResultFailure(state, {id, error}) {
        // state.all.samples = state.samples.map(sample => {
        //     if (sample.sampleId !== id) {
        //         // make copy of user without 'deleting:true' property
        //         const { deleting, ...sampleCopy } = sample;
        //         // return copy of user with 'deleteError:[error]' property
        //         return { ...sampleCopy, deleteError: error };
        //     }

        //     return sample;
        // })     
    },
    // getSampleIdRequest(state, sample){
    //     state.status = {getSampleId: true};
    //     state.sample = sample;
    // },
    // getSampleIdSuccess(state, sample){
    //     state.status = {getSampleId: true};
    //     state.sample = sample;
    // },
    // getSampleIdFailure(state, {id, error}){
    //     state.status = {};
    //     state.sample = null;
    // },
    testQualifiedSuccess(state, isQualified){
        state.all = {qualified: isQualified};
        console.log(state);
    },

    addNewSampleRequest(state, sample) {
        state.all.samples = sample;
    },
    addNewSampleSuccess(state, sample) {
        state.all.sample = sample;
        console.log(state);
    },
    addNewSampleFailure(state, error) {
        state.all.sample = null;
    }
};

export const samples = {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

Comment: I've tried to use watch function to see if I can track the status changes but it is still not working...

Comment: How is your store's state initialised?

Comment: I use ```Vuex.Store({modules:{samples})``` to initialize the store.

Comment: How **exactly** is your `samples` module state initialised?

Comment: I added my sample.module.js file above. Thanks!

Comment: The new code added doesn't match the old code. In one your mutations set `state.sample` but in the other, the same mutations set `state.all`

Comment: In any case, the problem is down to [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)... _"Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion"_

Comment: Yes, I also updated my page html as well. Let me update my new page html.

Answer (score -1):

In the mutation, you're updating the value in the "sample" singular form state but trying to access in map state with the name "samples" plural form state.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I've follow your instruction but it is still not working.